# Why does the first parallel Stream after a program starts run more slowly than the subsequent ones

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8

I wrote the following code to learn parallelStream.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> set = IntStream.iterate(2000000, x -> x - 1)
                .boxed()
                .limit(2000000)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            //================= parallelStream ===============
            LocalTime start = LocalTime.now();
            set.parallelStream().sorted().findFirst().get();
            Duration duration = Duration.between(start, LocalTime.now());
            System.out.println("parallelStream: " + duration.toMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I ran this program, I found that the first parallel stream was always much slower than the subsequent parallel streams.

Here are some test data:

```
parallelStream: 113
parallelStream: 24
parallelStream: 41
parallelStream: 14
parallelStream: 14

Process finished with exit code 0
```

-

```
parallelStream: 154
parallelStream: 25
parallelStream: 47
parallelStream: 13
parallelStream: 15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

See, the first parallel stream operation always takes several times as long as the subsequent parallel stream costs.
Why is that? I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Of course it should be like that since there are some data cache for later cases.

Comment: Don’t use `LocalTime.now()` to measure *elapsed time*. The local time is the one that can be adapted by NTP updates, be subject to leap seconds, etc. Use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) for measuring *elapsed time*. Besides that, in Java almost *everything* is slower when being executed the first time. Consider class loading, verifying and initialization, consider the JIT which only becomes active after identifying the hot spots, etc.